# Change Content-Disposition to open all image file files in a new tab

Tags: c#, asp.net, stream

Here's the logic for downloading the file.

It automatically downloads the file, whether it's a .jpg, .pdf, .zip or whatever, I would like it to only open in a new tab if it's an image file(jpg, png, etc.) and then everything else prompts for a download.

I feel like I'm missing something when it comes to solving this. :/

```
public void DownloadArchivedFiles(ArchiveType type, Object id, String fileName)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "filename=" + fileName);

        String path = Server.MapPath(String.Format("~/{0}Files/{1}", type, id));
        var fmFiles = new string[0];
        var files=new string[0];
        if(type==ArchiveType.Issue)
        { 
            fmFiles = _files.GetIssueFiles(new Guid(id.ToString())).Select(x => Server.MapPath("~" + x.FilePath)).ToArray();
        }else if(type==ArchiveType.Task)
        {
            fmFiles = _files.GetTaskFiles(int.Parse(id.ToString())).Select(x => Server.MapPath("~" + x.FilePath)).ToArray();
        }
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path) && !fmFiles.Any()) return;

        //String[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(String.Format("~/{0}Files/{1}", type, id)));
        try
        {
            files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(String.Format("~/{0}Files/{1}", type, id)));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            ;
        }

        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            zip.AddFiles(files, "/");
            if(fmFiles.Any())
            zip.AddFiles(fmFiles,"/");
            zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
        }
        HttpContext.Response.End();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't open a new tab by providing a header in the response.  It's too late.  By the time the response is being generated, the browser is already trying to get the response stream into the same tab, and the old document may already have been unloaded.

Instead, you need to change the way the *request* is sent.  Specifically, the link for the image must have the `_target="blank"` as an attribute.  This tells the browser to open up a new tab (or window, depending on the user's browser settings) and then request the image there.  You don't need to do anything special to the response headers at that point.

You should avoid `target="blank"` for your downloadable files (e.g. PDFs).  It'll work ok on some browsers, but on others you'll end up with unsightly zombie tabs.

Comment: I see, that's what I was trying to avoid, I wanted to have a browser universal way of doing this.